# Filter items in a ListView in real time

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My program generates ListView full of information. I type into a text box a name that might match one of the item names in the ListView. I want this typed name to weed out the names from the ListView that don't match.

For example, if I type in "abc", names like "uvw" and "xyz" wouldn't show up anymore, but "abc" and "abcde" would still show up in the list view.

The end goal is to be able to check the checkboxes next to the names I want, and search for more names, eventually selecting several, without resetting the checkboxes.

Right now I click a button and the ListView is populated:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> myList = getList();
    foreach(string s in myList)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```

`getList()` just returns a `List<string>` of all the names I want.

I can't figure out how to make the ListView update in real time when I type in my text box. I'm able to update it with a button click via repopulating the ListView based on looping through the List, and checking each name, but that's not what I want. It also doesn't retain checked check boxes, as it's a newly generated list each time.

I read about a "text change listener", but I'm not sure that's what I should be using here...

Comment: Would some sort of `KeyUp` event on a textbox work as a filter? I did something akin to that in WPF but it was on `ObservableCollection` so I don't know how exactly to filter `ListView`.

Comment: The only way to populate a WinForms ListView is to add items.  So, to filter would require some adding and removing.  Try a DataGridView instead

Comment: You could create a `ListView` subclass that maintains a collection of "visible" items and only adds these items each time the `ListView` is updated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25422372/8061994). Then you would just have to update the list of "visible" items in your custom `ListView` in a `TextBox.TextChanged` event handler attached to your `TextBox`

Comment: @Plutonix I guess I'm not married to the ListView. What does a DataGridView have that would do the trick?

Comment: Databinding....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With filtering you need some way of remembering which ListViewItems are selected, so instead of inserting all your ListViewItems into your listview you want to instantiate them in a master list. Then attach a TextChanged event handler to your text box and when the text changes you display the items.

```
List<ListViewItem> masterlist;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    masterlist = new List<ListViewItem>();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Populate the masterlist
    masterlist.Clear();
    foreach(string s in getList())
    {
        masterlist.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(s));
    }

    // Display the items in the listview
    DisplayItems();
}

private void DisplayItems()
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();

    // This filters and adds your filtered items to listView1
    foreach(ListViewItem item in masterlist.Where(lvi => lvi.Text.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower().Trim())))
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Re-display the items when the filter changes
    DisplayItems();
}
```

As you're dealing directly with ListViewItems in your `masterlist` they will retain their checked state when swapped in and out of `listView1`.

I have assumed that your filter textbox is called `textBox1`.

Comment: Very interesting idea. Trying this now!

Comment: I can't figure out an error I'm getting on the filtering part: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]'

Comment: What's the purpose of the "Cast" part here?

Comment: This line is throwing the error: listView1.Items.AddRange(masterlist.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(lvi => lvi.Text.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower().Trim())));

Comment: You can remove the cast. When I wrote the code I was thinking of picking the items from a `ListView` (ListView.Items is a ListViewItemCollection not a List so needs casting).

Comment: If I just use `listView1.Items.AddRange(masterlist.Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower().Trim()));` it complains that "cannot convert from string to listviewitem."

Comment: Seems that AddRange doesn't like taking a list. See the updated answer.

Comment: Scratch that. The update is working. Thank you so much, @Handbag Crab!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go for a full C# solution (rather than using any Javascript), as much as it pains me, I would suggest using an [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx).

Put your `ListBox` inside they the `<ContentTemplate>` section of the `<UpdatePanel>` then add an `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>` with the `ControlID` set to that of your textbox. Make sure that the `UpdateMode` property of the `UpdatePanel` is set to "Conditional".

On your `TextBox` you will also have to set the `AutoPostBack` property to `true`. On the `TextBox` itself you will have to create a `TextChanged` event handler, then in your code behind (`.cs` file) you will have the logic for your [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) handler which will filter the list then set the new value for your `ListBox`.

`UpdatePanel`s are ok for simply scenarios, but you can very easily get yourself into trouble by mis-using them.

Comment: Disregard as I see you're using WinForms, not ASP.NET

Comment: The question is about Winforms, not Webforms.